# Can I really use JSON to eliminate the need for tags and page mappings in Struts 2?

Tags: javascript, json, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts

This is something I've been thinking about a lot. What are the advantages and disadvantages of a design where the pages are un-mapped pure HTML and JavaScript and the data is all JSON pulled from the Struts 2?  No action mappings means relative page references so we don't have much use for the Struts 2 URL tags or any other tags for that matter.  Literally ANY information we need from the model can be retrieved through JSON or handled with a custom Interceptor. Session management for example is usually dealt with in an Interceptor anyways. I'm assuming that JavaScript can get information from the headers here which may not be correct. Please let me know if I'm wrong. Even if I am wrong, one might still use a hidden control or some other means to stash this type of information in. Regardless, I feel certain that it can be done although I am fuzzy on the specifics.

In a nutshell the end result would seem to be a pure HTML / JQuery UI which a UI-only developer, an expert on page design and usability can work with without ever needing to know Java. A person who's sole purpose is to manage the user experience from the UI side. With the use of tabs, menus pop-ups etc., pages might never need anything except JSON data which would enhance browser caching. This idea also greatly reduces the need for Web Services, since you already have a cleanly de-coupled model and view. We won't need OGNL or JSTL or have to mess with the value stack or type converters. If you are using Hibernate, I've already seen libraries out there that will convert Hibernate entities directly to JSON.

Am I completely off my rocker here?  Is it possible to get what Servlets and JSP promised without all the cruft?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're talking about a 'generic' sort of backend, that would just expose the data in your app to client-side JS. That is perfectly feasible, but your backend will still have to do some work specific to the app and its features - only the backend can deal correctly with authentication and access control.

Comment: I'm not sure. If I ask for data that I am not authorized, couldn't the JSON result, which IS on an app server, indicate this? We could then have the JavaScript respond accordingly.  I mean sure, you could turn off JavaScript and hit the JSON results but since those are on an app server, the system could know your authorizations and permissions, couldn't it?

Comment: Oh sure, that's all I meant - that the server has to control that stuff, it can't be left up to the client to decide what the user does or doesn't have permission to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your final sentence means at all. Not sure what you mean by "reducing the need for web services", because what you describe are web services returning JSON.

That aside; of course you can do everything client-side via JavaScript and get only JSON from S2. If your client-side framework supports it, I don't really think there *are* any drawbacks, as long as your app doesn't require data-specific bookmarking or you're using a JS library that supports it.

The level of caching may be slightly higher, but a well-designed, non-JSON-only app can do quite a bit of caching anyway, so I'm not sure how much of a boost you'd get from that--but certainly some.

Depending on the browser you may run into a variety of issues regarding memory usage, leaks, etc. which can be difficult (or impossible) to track down or resolve, but depending on your app's usage patterns, and your user's browser preferences, this may never become an issue.

With modern browsers, and modern client-side JS frameworks, this kind of app is completely possible, and is being done more and more--it's not a unique idea.

Comment: Well, I suppose you are correct. I meant Web Services as in SOAP or REST. Not a unique idea? Great. If it were a unique idea then this would be cause for more concern rather than less. ;-)

Comment: Just to make this complete, if you want to SEND to, rather than receive JSON from, Struts 2 actions, what you are looking for, of course, is an Interceptor which needs to be added to the stack. You also need to make sure you set the content type to JSON.